# Can't understand this SQL statement? Why is it generating an error

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, error-handling

I am learning SQL through a book, and it gives the following code for error handling

```
Create procedure sp_ErrorHandling
@SupplierID int,
@ProductID int,
@ProductName text
AS
Begin TRY
Insert into tbls_products_sp(ProductID,SupplierID,ProductName)
Values(@SupplierID,@ProductID,@ProductName)
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
Print 'Supplier does not exist'
END CATCH

exec sp_ErrorHandling @ProductID=73,@SupplierID=11,@ProductName='Chocolate'

exec sp_ErrorHandling @ProductID=73,@SupplierID=11,@ProductName='Chocolate'
```

It says because there's no supplierID with a value 11 it will generate an error. 
And when I use supplierID with a values 11, it doesn't generate an error.

My question is when we are using an INSERT statement, isn't the point of insert statement to enter new records in the existing table. So if I give values for new records, shouldn't they be added to the table instead of an error?

Comment: You're inserting product id into supplier and supplier into product

Comment: It sounds like there might be a constraint on the table that requires the foreign key to exist -- is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the book is trying to teach you the concept of foreign key constraints.

With a foreign key constraint if you insert a record into table B and the foreign key value does not exist in table A, SQL Server will raise an error.

Imagine you have a table of country_codes and a table of customers. You define a foreign key constraint that says when you insert a record into customers the countrycode value must exist in the country_codes table.

So when you create a new customer record if the countrycode value is not in the country_codes table an error will be raised.

Comment: So I added an error message line to the code. This is what I get                Error Message:-
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_tbls_Products_sp'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tbls_Products_sp'. The duplicate key value is (9).                                                                                                         It shows a constraint of Primary key, and the same message comes up with both 9 and 11 as the supplierID value. Can you help me understand this?